# Pentaho data integration with REST

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I am trying to connect to a rest API over SSL with un/pwd authentication.  I am able to browse the URL - however when I run the job nothing happens. Essentially I just want to connect tot he server and output the data in an xml file.

Thank you in advance

JOB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation-steps>
 <steps>
  <step>
    <name>REST Client</name>
    <type>Rest</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <method>GET</method>
    <url>https:&#47;&#47;blah&#47;services&#47;companies</url>
    <urlInField>N</urlInField>
    <dynamicMethod>N</dynamicMethod>
    <methodFieldName/>
    <urlField/>
    <bodyField/>
    <httpLogin>tbrown</httpLogin>
    <httpPassword></httpPassword>
    <httpPassword>Encrypted 2be98afc86aa7f2e4fa498679d99a9cce</httpPassword>
    <proxyHost/>
    <proxyPort/>
    <preemptive>N</preemptive>
    <trustStoreFile/>
    <trustStorePassword/>
    <headers>
      </headers>
    <parameters>
      </parameters>
    <result>
      <name>REST3_DATA</name>
      <code>REST3_STATUS</code>
      <response_time/>
      </result>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>114</xloc>
      <yloc>185</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>XML Output</name>
    <type>XMLOutput</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <name_space/>
    <xml_main_element>Rows</xml_main_element>
    <xml_repeat_element>Row</xml_repeat_element>
    <file>
      <name>C:\temp\output.txt</name>
      <extention>xml</extention>
      <servlet_output>N</servlet_output>
      <do_not_open_newfile_init>N</do_not_open_newfile_init>
      <split>N</split>
      <add_date>N</add_date>
      <add_time>N</add_time>
      <SpecifyFormat>N</SpecifyFormat>
      <omit_null_values>N</omit_null_values>
      <date_time_format/>
      <add_to_result_filenames>N</add_to_result_filenames>
      <zipped>N</zipped>
      <splitevery>0</splitevery>
    </file>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>REST3_DATA</name>
        <element>DATA</element>
        <type>-</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>REST3_STATUS</name>
        <element/>
        <type>Integer</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <nullif/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>0</precision>
      </field>
    </fields>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>332</xloc>
      <yloc>174</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

    </steps>
<order>
  <hop> <from>REST Client</from><to>XML Output</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  </order>
  <notepads>
   </notepads>
 </transformation-steps>
```

LOG:

> 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - We have 0
>   connections... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - Reading
>   2 steps... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - Looking at
>   step #0 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - Looking at
>   step #1 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - We have 1
>   hops... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - Looking at hop
>
> ## 0 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - nr of steps read :
>
> 2 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - nr of hops  read : 1
>   2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Spoon - Transformation opened. 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - Spoon - Launching transformation [test]... 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution. 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - test - Dispatching started for transformation [test]
>   2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - Nr of arguments detected:0  2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - test - This is not a replay transformation 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - Transformation metadata - Natural sort of steps executed in
>   {0} ms ({1} time previous steps calculated) 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test
>   - I found 2 different steps to launch. 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test -
>   Allocating rowsets... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test -  Allocating rowsets
>   for step 0 --> REST Client 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test -   prevcopies =
>   1, nextcopies=1 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - Transformation allocated
>   new rowset [REST Client.0 - XML Output.0] 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test -
>   Allocated 1 rowsets for step 0 --> REST Client   2011/07/28 15:42:10 -
>   test -  Allocating rowsets for step 1 --> XML Output 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - test -  Allocated 1 rowsets for step 1 --> XML Output
>   2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - Allocating Steps & StepData... 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - test -  Transformation is about to allocate step [REST
>   Client] of type [Rest] 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test -   Step has
>   nrcopies=1 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - REST Client.0 - distribution
>   activated 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - REST Client.0 - Starting allocation of
>   buffers & new threads... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - REST Client.0 - Step
>   info: nrinput=0 nroutput=1 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - REST Client.0 -
>   output rel. is  1:1 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - REST Client.0 - Found output
>   rowset [REST Client.0 - XML Output.0] 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - REST
>   Client.0 - Finished dispatching 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - 
>   Transformation has allocated a new step: [REST Client].0 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - test -  Transformation is about to allocate step [XML
>   Output] of type [XMLOutput] 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test -   Step has
>   nrcopies=1 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - distribution activated
>   2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Starting allocation of buffers &
>   new threads... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Step info:
>   nrinput=1 nroutput=0 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Got previous
>   step from [XML Output] #0 --> REST Client 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML
>   Output.0 - input rel is 1:1 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Found
>   input rowset [REST Client.0 - XML Output.0] 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML
>   Output.0 - Finished dispatching 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - 
>   Transformation has allocated a new step: [XML Output].0 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - test - This transformation can be replayed with replay
>   date: 2011/07/28 15:42:10 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - Initialising 2
>   steps... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - REST Client.0 - Running on slave server
>
> ## 0/1. 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Running on slave server
>
> ## 0/1. 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Opening output stream in
>
> encoding: UTF-8 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - Step [REST Client.0]
>   initialized flawlessly. 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test - Step [XML
>   Output.0] initialized flawlessly. 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - test -
>   Transformation has allocated 2 threads and 1 rowsets. 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - REST Client.0 - Starting to run... 2011/07/28 15:42:10 -
>   REST Client.0 - Signaling 'output done' to 1 output rowsets.
>   2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Starting to run... 2011/07/28
>   15:42:10 - REST Client.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0,
>   U=0, E=0) 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Signaling 'output done'
>   to 0 output rowsets. 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - XML Output.0 - Finished
>   processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=0) 2011/07/28 15:42:10 - Spoon
>   - The transformation has finished!!

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but I thought I would make a suggestion if anyone stumbles onto this page.

Make sure you have a generate row step as the first step because you can't start a transformation with a REST Client step as it is a lookup step and not an input step.